# CRON[83463]: Failure setting user credentials

Tags: ldap, cron, pam

I have a number of docker containers, all set up mostly identically, which successfully use cron to run nightly backup jobs.

I have another container, set up mostly identically, which tries, and fails, to use cron to run a nightly backup job.

I installed rsyslog to get more information, and when cron runs root's crontab I see the following entry in the syslog file:

```
CRON[83463]: Failure setting user credentials
```

The one difference between this container and all the others is that this one allows users to log in using LDAP. It has the following extra lines in the Dockerfile:

```
RUN echo '*;*;*;Al0000-2400;svn' >> /etc/security/group.conf
COPY pam_group /usr/share/pam-configs/groups
RUN echo "session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel umask=077" >> /etc/pam.d/common-session
RUN sed -i 's#\(.*pam_ldap.so.*\)#auth    required     pam_group.so\n\1#' /etc/pam.d/common-auth
RUN sed -i 's#^passwd:.*#passwd:  files ldap systemd#;s#^group:.*#group:   files ldap systemd#;s#^shadow:.*#shadow:  files ldap#' /etc/nsswitch.conf
```

The `pam_group` file looks like:

```
Name: activate /etc/security/group.conf
Default: yes

Priority: 900
Auth-Type: Primary Auth:
        required                        pam_group.so
```

Clearly, something about setting up the LDAP, and trying to ensure that all users get added to the `svn` group (which doesn't work at all) broke the root user session for cron.

I have looked all over the internet, but not found this specific error. I have tried related solutions, but nothing works.

UPDATE:

pam.d/common-auth looks like:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]  pam_unix.so nullok_secure
auth    required     pam_group.so
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]  pam_ldap.so use_first_pass
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
auth    requisite           pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
auth    required            pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
auth    optional            pam_cap.so
```

pam.d/cron looks like:

```
@include common-auth

# Sets the loginuid process attribute
session    required     pam_loginuid.so

# Read environment variables from pam_env's default files, /etc/environment
# and /etc/security/pam_env.conf.
session       required   pam_env.so

# In addition, read system locale information
session       required   pam_env.so envfile=/etc/default/locale

@include common-account
@include common-session-noninteractive 

# Sets up user limits, please define limits for cron tasks
# through /etc/security/limits.conf
session    required   pam_limits.so
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is probably that the root user isn't in LDAP; you'll need to include `pam_unix.so` in `/etc/pam.d/cron` somehow.

For example:

```
auth    [success=2 default=ignore]      pam_unix.so nullok_secure
@include common-auth
```

Assuming that `common-auth` begins something like this:

```
auth    [success=1 default=ignore]      pam_ldap.so
auth    requisite                       pam_deny.so
auth    required                        pam_permit.so
```

Comment: I added more information to the question. I think I have what you suggest in that I have a pam_unix.so "auth" line before the LDAP lines, in a file (common-auth) which is included in the pam.d/cron file.

Comment: The `success=2` bit is wrong. It will skip to pam_deny.so. Make it `success=3`.

Comment: Thanks for the help and advice. I'll have a go at it tomorrow. So I can learn more I have a question. Your example gives `"success=2"` and that's the default too. What does the number signify and why should it be 3?

Comment: The number tells PAM how many of the next modules in this stack to skip if the outcome reported by this module is "success". It's a conditional `goto`, if you will. In your config, `success=2` causes `pam_group` and `pam_ldap` to be skipped if `pam_unix` succeeds. You also want to skip `pam_deny`, because that's just a catch-all to deny everything. The idea with the `success=X` rules is to skip past `pam_deny`, to any optional modules.

Comment: Thanks. That really helps.